# TypeError: currentUser is null in firebase react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, react-hooks

I found different already answered questions to my question, but the don't help.

I use a custom context to call the `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged()` and set the `currentUser`.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import app from "../firebase";

export const AuthContext = React.createContext();

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    app.auth().onAuthStateChanged(setCurrentUser);
  }, []);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ currentUser }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

In my component I call the `AuthContext` and the `currentUser`:

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import app from "./firebase";
import { AuthContext } from "./Auth/Auth";

function MyComponent() {
  const [invoices, setInvoices] = useState([]);
  const { currentUser } = useContext(AuthContext);

  const getInvoices = () => {
    const database = app.firestore();
    const unsubscribe = database
      .collection("invoices")
      .where("uid", "==", currentUser.uid) // HERE currentUser IS NULL
      .orderBy("date", "desc")
      .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
        setInvoices(
          snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() }))
        );
      });

    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    };
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getInvoices();
  }, []);

  return (<> ... </>);
}
export default MyComponent;
```

I believe my issue has something to do with promises and the user is not yet loaded. But still I don't know what to do here.

Comment: I would debug if `onAuthStateChanged((user) => console.log(user))` shows something first or not.

Answer (score 2):

The potential issue could be the value of `currentUser` returns a bit later so you need to add an extra check in your `MyComponent` component.

I would add `null` check for `currentUser` and extend the dependency array as:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (currentUser) {
     getInvoices();
  }
}, [currentUser]);
```

Probably in the first round the `useEffect` callback was running once `currentUser` was still `null`.

Comment: @T.Karter Awesome, happy to help! :)